# How to remove a Raid 1 subgroup from a Raid 10 array?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, dell-poweredge, raid10

I have a RAID 10 array with 3 subgroups of drives in RAID 1, like in the image below

[Raid 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ6Ut.png)

Is it possible to remove an entire subgroup (2 disks) without losing the entire Array? The RAID 10 will work normally with only 4 disks?

If it is possible, how do i do it? I use a PowerEdge R710

Answer (score 0):

No - in a RAID 10, removing any subgroup of disks will cause the destruction of the RAID0. If you had a RAID 01 - yes, you could remove one of the subgroup RAID 0s without problem.

Comment: You're right - fact checked myself and fixed it.